# parse huge json(28MB) file from assets folder using jackson Android

Tags: android

I am new In android.I want To parse Data from Huge Json(28 MB) File. I have Tried but didn't success.I am developing Weather app .In which Country and City Required .I have Found json file In openWeather Api and fetch data also.But File is So Large and I want To manage CountryWise city So I am trying to fetch only city Name and Country and merge Country wise city But i didn't read File .I Have Try so many things to overcome the problem.Please Help me to learn New Things Also.

This is My Main Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Map<String,String> CountryListHash ;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        (findViewById(R.id.B1)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                InputStream is = null;
                BufferedReader br=null;
                ObjectMapper mapper;
                City jsoncity;
                CountryListHash = new TreeMap<>();
                 StringBuffer json;
                    try {
                   br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open("city.list.json"), "UTF-8"));
                        json = new StringBuffer();
                        String tmp;
                        while ((tmp = br.readLine()) != null) {
                            json.append(tmp);
                            mapper = new ObjectMapper();
                            jsoncity  = mapper.readValue(json.toString(),City.class);
                            CountryListHash.put( jsoncity.getCountry(),(jsoncity.getCity()));
                            Log.e("City",  ""  + jsoncity.getCountry() +" " +jsoncity.getCity());
                        }
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    finally {
                        if (br != null) {
                            try {
                                br.close();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                //log the exception
                            }
                        }
                    }


            }
        });
    }
```

This is My City class

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)

public class City {


 private String name;

 private String country;

 public City(){}

 public String setCity(String name){
   return  this.name=name;
 }

 public String setCountry(String country){
      return this.country=country;
 }



  public String getCity(){
     return name;
  }

   public String getCountry(){
      return country;
   }

}
```

This is My JSon File

```
[
  {
    "id": 707860,
    "name": "Hurzuf",
    "country": "UA",
    "coord": {
      "lon": 34.283333,
      "lat": 44.549999
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 519188,
    "name": "Novinki",
    "country": "RU",
    "coord": {
      "lon": 37.666668,
      "lat": 55.683334
    }
  },
...And Many More
```

Comment: What is the exact problem you are facing? Do you get exceptions?

Comment: I Unable to fetch whole data  and no exception..@Minas Mina

Comment: So what happens? Do you get a message that the app is not responding? Please share more information so that we can help :)

Comment: Its actually not give a message that app is not responding ..Its Unable to read whole data file..And not Give any error ..@Minas Mina

Comment: have you tried with a smaller json to be sure that the problem is really file size?

Comment: Ya  i have Used Small Size file its Work Correctly But I have Only used Json ..Not used Jackson .. But I have to tried In Big File  I have searched And Found parse Big Json file through Gson,jackson .I have tried Gson aslo Its also not get whole data..So I think its time to try Jackson Its aslo come the same problem

Comment: Maybe you could parse it in chunks. It should be easy since it is an array and the objects have few keys.

Comment: jackson unable to parse whole file at whole time @Minas Mina

Comment: tell me how  to use jackson to fetch whole big data file at once.

Comment: tell me also about GSON for same problem @MinasMina

Comment: @VivekModi You have a `Log.e()` statement in your while-loop. Is it being printed in the logcat continuously or not?

Comment: Its not printing anything ...In Logcat @Minas Mina

Comment: @VivekModi There is an empty catch block. Please check that. You can do `throw new RuntimeException(e);` so that you won't miss it if it happens.

Answer (score 0):

As I know, the onClick callback is running on the UI thread and you shouldn't do any IO operation on the UI thread. Try to create a new thread and move all of the operations which are in your onClick callback to the new thread. Hope it can help you.